# swiftui list not working when put into ZStack

Tags: list, swiftui

I use ZStack to combine a list and Color, after doing it, List will not scroll and there's no output when clicking the text.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{

            List{
                ForEach(1...30, id: \.self){ i in
                    Text("ROW \(i)")
                        .font(.system(size: 40))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("clicked \(i)")
                    }

                }
            }

            Color.black.opacity(0.2)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move Color before List and it will work. See the altered code below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.black.opacity(0.2)
            List{
                ForEach(1...30, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("ROW \(i)")
                        .font(.system(size: 40))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("clicked \(i)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it isn't working — probably a bug — but you can (and probably should) do this instead.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(1...30, id: \.self){ i in
                Text("ROW \(i)")
                    .font(.system(size: 40))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("clicked \(i)")
                }
            }
        }.background(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
    }
}
```