# List not scrolling (in SwiftUI -- to disambiguate from other questions)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Using SwiftUI, I have a List of items retrieved from CoreData.  Everything I read makes it look like the list should be something I can scroll normally, but in both the simulator and running on an iPad, the List doesn't scroll.

Clearly there is some piece missing, but I can't seem to find what it is.  The list populates correctly, but it simply won't scroll.

```
struct PeopleList : View {    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
     
     @FetchRequest(
        entity: Person.entity(),
         sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Person.lastName, ascending: true),           
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Person.firstName, ascending: true)
         ]
     ) var people: FetchedResults<Person>
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            List(self.people, id: \.self) { person in
                Text(person.descriptionForList())                                             
             }                          
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 200)
        .modifier(RoundedEdge(width: 4, color: Color(red: 0.6, green: 0.6, blue: 0.6), cornerRadius: 10))
        .padding(10)
    }
}
```

Things that didn't change anything:

- Removing the ZStack { }
- Replacing the List with a simple `List(0...100, id: \.self) { item in Text("hey \(item)")  }` -- still won't scroll.
- Adding a `.frame()` to the List() itself.
- (***added***) removing the `.frame` `.modifier` and `.padding` all accomplished nothing.

This is not about (the following topics have Q&A's addressing them, but not this issue):

- programmatic scrolling
- disabling scrolling
- scroll indicators
- ScrollView
- UIKit

How can I track down what might be preventing the List() from scrolling?

Comment: What is the `RoundedEdge` modifier? Did you try to remove it as well?

Comment: Recreated without RoundedEdge and scrolling is working for me

Comment: Does Person contain a unique field e.g. id? Did you try using a unique identifier instead of `self`? e.g. `List(self.people, id: \.id) { person in`

Comment: Commented out the `.modifier(RoundedEdge())`, no change.  The list populates fine, and when I make the list as simply being numbers 1...100, same behavior, so not thinking it's a matter of the `.id` either.  Maybe an issue with the View where this struct is showing up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, the issue wasn't with anything in the struct that was posed above; it all had to do with the View where that struct was being used.  Specifically, when a `Color()` -- even of `.opacity(0)` -- was in a `ZStack` sitting "above" the `List()`, the latter stops scrolling.  Displays fine, but just won't scroll.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60794878/swiftui-list-not-working-when-put-into-zstack) describes the same thing happening, albeit in somewhat different circumstances.

I'll leave this question up, since somebody else may be at the same place I was, "why isn't my List() scrolling?", rather than "why isn't my List() in a ZStack scrolling?"  Hopefully a version of Swift later than 13 will fix this behavior!